# model got 'undefined' when $setValidity set to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form with one input field, and I validate that input when the value changes by using $setValidity .But the problem is when $setValidity set to false (invalid) the model is no longer updating, it holds value 'undefined' .

Here is my HTML :

```
<form name="frmEnrollPaymentPlan" novalidate  autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':(frmEnrollPaymentPlan.dwnAmt.$invalid && !frmEnrollPaymentPlan.dwnAmt.$pristine)||frmEnrollPaymentPlan.dwnAmt.$error.validateDownPaymentAmount}">
    <label>Downpayment</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dwnAmt" ng-model="EnrollPaymentPlanViewModel.DownPaymentAmount" required ng-change="downPaymentChanged()" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
    <span ng-show="frmEnrollPaymentPlan.dwnAmt.$error.validateDownPaymentAmount" ng-class="{'error':frmEnrollPaymentPlan.dwnAmt.$error.validateDownPaymentAmount}">Cannot be less than down payment amount</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

and Here is my javascript code:

```
$scope.downPaymentChanged = function () {
if (!isNaN($scope.EnrollPaymentPlanViewModel.DownPaymentAmount)) {
    var downPaymentAmount = parseFloat($scope.EnrollPaymentPlanViewModel.DownPaymentAmount);
    var minDownPaymentAmount = parseFloat($scope.EnrollPaymentPlanViewModel.MinDownPaymentAmount);

    if (downPaymentAmount < minDownPaymentAmount) {
        $scope.frmEnrollPaymentPlan.dwnAmt.$setValidity("validateDownPaymentAmount", false);    
    }
    else {
        $scope.frmEnrollPaymentPlan.dwnAmt.$setValidity("validateDownPaymentAmount", true);   
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean your model is no longer updating? I tried the code above and I see that $scope.EnrollPaymentPlanViewModel.DownPaymentAmount is still getting the new values even after validity is false.

Comment: @noveyak , actually the problem is with the angular version I used version AngularJS v1.3.0 but its working fine on AngularJS v1.2.26 ,so why setValidity is not working on v1.3.0 and whats the alternate for it

Comment: Hmm, best of luck then. I'm still not quite sure whats wrong from this plunker I set up here http://plnkr.co/edit/fvZ5TQA1mUCaMgFPS2Bf?p=preview. Code seems to function as intended.